# CSS/JavaScript: Liquid Design issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to make a website similar to another one. On their website they use JavaScript to change the padding on the first section to keep it in the windows viewport. I have done this, but now I have an issue with making the button move the way theirs move when the window size is changed.

See the video below, basically when I make the height smaller (to a certain extent) the button should move up, but on my copy it doesn't as I can't figure out how they have done it. The video below shows their CSS Code and HTML and no values seem to be changes by JavaScript to make the button move, but it does, the padding of the element about doesn't change from 96.

[YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/90sKFIhGo0k)

Edit:
My code so far, html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section id="header" class="arrows" style="padding:280px 0px">
            <header>
                <h1>Mobile Paint Solutions</h1>
                <p>Since 1980</p>
            </header>
            <footer>
                <a onClick="test()" href="" class="button white">About</a>
            </footer>
        </section>
        <section id="banner" class="arrows">
            <header>
                <div>
                    <h1>About Us</h1>
                    <p>We are a proud company and have been providing a superb service for many years. You may read some of our reviews or sumbmit your own below! </p>
                </div>
            </header>
            <footer>
                <a href="#banner" class="button white">About</a>
            </footer>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS for the #header:

```
body {
        text-align:center;
        font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background-image:url(images/bg.jpg);
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    header { margin-bottom: 1em; }
    * { 
        margin:0; 
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* Header and Title Styles */
    #header {
        display:inline-block;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        color:#FFF;
        cursor:default;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #header header p:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        border-top: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        margin: 4px 0 0.8em 0;
    }
    #header header p {
        border-top:solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        letter-spacing:3px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-size:1em;
        margin-top:1em; 
    }
    #header h1 {
        font-size:2.5em;
        font-weight:bold;
        letter-spacing:3px;
    }
```

Here is a [link](http://pixelarity.com/items/demos/overflow/green/) to their website so you can see it work.

Comment: Maybe they use the `position:absolute; bottom: Xpx;` to make that button keep a distance from the window's bottom. Anyway, this is not how a question should be asked here, you should post code here or we can't help you much.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Only code I have is for the button, it won't be absolutely positioned as then when I scroll down the button will be going down too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, it seem that the footer needed to be positioned absolute, changed around some other code for example positioned the header relative, then it seemed to start to work.